# How do I make a responsive image map where the image AND hotspots automatically resize with window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

First off, I apologize if this question is worded weird and off, I'm trying to put in code and make my questioning better since my last questions were erased. I just need to get help with this coding.
I have tried several jquery/javascripts on the image map and none have worked. The ones I've tried are at: 
view-source:http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/IMG/resizeimg.html
https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

My code for image map:

```
<img src="images/background.jpg" usemap="#banner" />
<map name="banner">
<area shape="rect" coords="109,7,435,324"
href="http://www.instituteforcreativelearners.org/" target="_blank" alt="The Institute
for Creative Learners">

<area shape="rect" coords="976,98,1295,278" href="http://www.adoptioncovenant.org/"
target="_blank" alt="Adoption Covenant">
</map>
```

I have also tried saving the image as a SVG file and it still doesn't resize the links/hotspots along with the image. (This is the straight svg code but I did add the links to the rectangles when I tried it)

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;"
xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
 x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2020 600" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2020 600;"
xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:none;}
</style>
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="2021" height="601" xlink:href="background.jpg" 
transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0.5 -0.5)">

</image>
<rect x="143.3" y="0" class="st0" width="468" height="454.8"/>
<rect x="1310.4" y="127.7" class="st0" width="468" height="249"/>
</svg>
```

Is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've not attempted this before, but a possible solution may be to use jQuery/JS to determine the window width, and update the image and map based on that. 
First approach would be to set separate widths based on devices. The second approach would be a dynamic one using window.resize so that the values update dynamically based on the window width.

So first approach would look something like...

```
$(window).resize(function(){

if($(window).width()>=640){
    //set your html for this screen width
}
else if($(window).width()>=320){
//set your html for this screen width
}
});
```

And the second approach would be something like

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var x, y, imgMap;
x = $(window).width() - 200;//update coords...

imgMap = "<html for img map here>";

}
});
```

Hope this helps a bit...

[Here's info on resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)